Python script called from Excel VBA cannot access files, but script works when called without Excel
An Excel VBA script calls on a python script. The Python script accesses a different Excel file and manipulates it. When the python script is ran normally, it works as it is supposed to, but when called from Excel, it cannot find the file it is looking for.

The Python script opens the document with this:
Control = "Sales_Values.xlsx" 
xldata = pd.read_excel(Control, engine='openpyxl')

The Excel Script call the Python with this:
Shell FilePath, vbNormalFocus

The Excel script is calling the right program, the python script can open the file when ran outside of Excel, the file that I am trying to open is closed so there is no permission errors.
I have tried it with the below line of code to ensure there is no permission errors:
Workbooks("Sales_Values.xlsx").Close


Try using absolute address ie Control = "c:\path\to\folder\Sales_Values.xlsx" 

If the file is in the same directory as your python script, then you might check out How to refer to relative paths of resources when working with a code repository

The issue is still there when using the absolute path, the addresses should all be correct as I can run the program directly and it works fine

Try Control = "c:/path/to/folder/Sales_Values.xlsx"
